# How to connect Windows 7 PC to Windows 8.1 printer?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have 2 PCs: A windows 8.1 PC ("frisbee2") hard-wired to the router via Ethernet cable and connected directly to an HP printer via cable. I also have a windows 7 PC ("home-office") in another part of the house connected to the Internet hard wired by Ethernet to the router. I cannot get home-office to successfully connect to the frisbee2 printer. The PCs can see each other, ping each other, and connect to each other via UNC. But when I try to connect to the printer from home-office to frisbee2, I always get the error "Cannot connect to printer".

I have tried going the HomeGroup path, but no luck. home-office can't connect to the homegroup I created on frisbee2 and I'm certain the password is correct.

I have tried the following suggestions, but no luck:

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982728
2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982643
3. http://scottiestech.info/2010/09/21/how-to-fix-windows-cannot-connect-to-printer-errors-in-windows-7/

Why can't home-office connect to frisbee2's shared printer even though it can see it?

Comment: Did you try accessing the remote machine by IP instead of UNC?
Try: \\ip_address

Comment: UNC pathing is working right, but still no luck connecting to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Start button, then select Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners . Select Add a printer or scanner. Wait for your device to find nearby printers, choose the one you want, and then select Add device.